# Using address of array of struct instead of pointer to struct gives warning

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct, compiler-warnings

I am getting a compiler warning when I try to use the address of the first element of an array of structs instead of a pointer to the struct.  The following compiles without a warning:

```
typedef struct {
    int val;
} my_struct;

typedef my_struct my_t[1];

typedef struct {
    my_struct **t_ptr;
} my_other_struct;

int main(void)
{
    my_struct t0;
    my_t t1 = {t0};
    t1->val = 0;

    my_other_struct t2;
    my_struct *t_array[] = {t1};
    t2.t_ptr = t_array;

    return 0;
}
```

But when I change the two occurrences of `my_struct *` to `my_t`, (

```
typedef struct {
    int val;
} my_struct;

typedef my_struct my_t[1];

typedef struct {
    my_t *t_ptr;
} my_other_struct;

int main(void)
{
    my_struct t0;
    my_t t1 = {t0};
    t1->val = 0;

    my_other_struct t2;
    my_t t_array[] = {t1};
    t2.t_ptr = t_array;

    return 0;
}
```

) I get the warning

```
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:20:5: warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
     my_t t_array[] = {t1};
     ^
test.c:20:5: warning: (near initialization for ‘t_array[0][0].val’) [enabled by default]
```

Why am I getting this warning and am I doing something incorrectly?

**EDIT:**

Here is some code that I was using as a reference:

```
typedef fmpz fmpz_t[1];

typedef struct
{
    fmpz * coeffs;
    slong alloc;
    slong length;
} fmpz_poly_struct;

typedef fmpz_poly_struct fmpz_poly_t[1];

typedef struct
{
    fmpz_poly_struct *num;
    fmpz_poly_struct *den;
} fmpz_poly_q_struct;

typedef fmpz_poly_q_struct fmpz_poly_q_t[1];

void fmpz_poly_q_zero(fmpz_poly_q_t rop)
{
    fmpz_poly_zero(rop->num);
    fmpz_poly_set_si(rop->den, 1);
}

void fmpz_poly_q_one(fmpz_poly_q_t rop)
{
    fmpz_poly_set_si(rop->num, 1);
    fmpz_poly_set_si(rop->den, 1);
}

void fmpz_poly_q_neg(fmpz_poly_q_t rop, const fmpz_poly_q_t op)
{
    fmpz_poly_neg(rop->num, op->num);
    fmpz_poly_set(rop->den, op->den);
}
```

I do see now that they use a `_struct *` instead of a `_t` in the `fmpz_poly_q_t` struct.

Comment: Don't `typedef` arrays or pointers! Think  about what `my_t` is and what you are declaring.

Comment: Pointers are not arrays. Arrays are not pointers. Don't mix them.

Comment: @Olaf there's nothing wrong with typedefing arrays.

Comment: @n.m.: It is far by most times a bad idea, like `typedef`ing pointers. For a beginner it is good advice not to. An expert may know the exceptions (there are none for object pointers, though)

Comment: @n.m. IMHO it's bad practice.

Comment: I was just following the practice that FLINT uses: http://flintlib.org/

Comment: @Olaf no, they are not like each other.

Comment: What kind of practice? Can you show their code you are using as an example?

Comment: @n.m. I posted the code.

Comment: You just show the  `[1]` typedefs, which are pretty bad by themselves, but they are not used in the fragment you have posted.

Comment: @n.m. I posted a few of the small functions (the functions for polynomial quotients call the functions for polynomials).

Comment: *In a function prototype*, an array parameter is quietly replaced by a pointer, so `void fmpz_poly_q_zero(fmpz_poly_q_t rop)` is 100% equivalent to `void fmpz_poly_q_zero(fmpz_poly_q_struct*  rop)`. Don't emulate this style.

Comment: @JacobBond the issue with `typedef`'ing pointers, etc. is that it **hides** the actual level of *inderection* associated with that variable. Yes it can be convenient to not have to put a `'*'` before the variable name, but 300 lines down in code it just sews seeds of confusion of WTF the variable actually is. While learning, you benefit from always dealing with the *exact* variable at issue, not some alias to it.

Comment: when typedef'ing a struct, use code similar to: `typedef struct tagname newname;`   Note that struct that does not have a tag name should not be typedef'd   One vary good method is to separate the struct definition from the typedef statement.

Comment: that posted code that results in the compiler warning also results in several other warnings from the compiler.  However, the main problem is the convoluted mess that is the data definitions